# String value in byte[] c#

Tags: c#, sql, string, byte, varbinary

I have to do a query to insert a value in a SQL table. The type of the value is varbinary and I have a string to insert with an hex value in it. So I tried to use the SQL Convert Function like this:

```
using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Link] ([Record]) values (CONVERT(varbinary,@myrecord);", dbConn))

dbCommand.Parameters.Add("myrecord", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = recordString;
```

but I have this Error: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a 
Byte[].

So I tried to convert my string to byte[], but all the function I found also on this site convert my string to byte changing its value, so it's not good because my string has inside the value I need to insert in the table.

Recap: I have a string with this value: "0x54000000006C00000000099W043100300030003100" how can I add it in a SQL table with a varbinary field?

Comment: If you are using the CONVERT function in your sqlcommand, why are you trying to add a VarBinary parameter? In mean, doesn't this work?: `dbCommand.Parameters.Add("myrecord", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = recordString;`

Comment: when I tried this the value of my string is converted and not what I wanted.

Comment: Example is not a valid hex string, there is a "W" in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i think i understand now. If you are using sql server 2008+, you can do this:

```
using (SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Link] ([Record]) values (CONVERT(varbinary,@myrecord,1);", dbConn))

dbCommand.Parameters.Add("myrecord", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = recordString;
```

Notice the `1` in `CONVERT(varbinary,@myrecord,1)`. Btw, the example number you gave us is not a valid Hex number...

More info: [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.120).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can and should be able to do this make sure you adjust the VarBinary Size to fit your case

```
using(SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Link] ([Record]) values(@myrecord);", dbCon))
{
    // Replace 8000, below, with the correct size of the field
    dbCommand.Parameters.Add("@myrecord", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, recordString.Length).Value = recordString;
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();//wrap around a try catch if you need to catch exceptions
}
```

Comment: I change 8000 with 448 (myvarbinary size) and I have the same error again: Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Byte[]

Comment: @Heisenberg you may need to change your datatype to `System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar`

Comment: @Heisenberg did that fix the issue